# d3 select throws invalid query selector error

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

This is the structure of my SVG elements:

```
<g class="point" transform="translate(241,197)">
  <circle></circle>
  <text class="pointIndex" x="-4px" y="-10px">1</text>
  <g class="deletePoint" transform="translate(0,16)">
    <circle></circle>
    <text x="-3px" y="3px">x</text>
  </g>
</g>
```

I created the following function:

```
  function deletePoint(deleteCircle) {
    var circleText = d3.select(deleteCircle.parentNode + '> text')
  }
```

`console.log(deleteCircle)` returns:

```
 <g class="deletePoint" transform="translate(0,16)">
    <circle></circle>
    <text x="-3px" y="3px">x</text>
 </g>
```

What I want is to find the text here: `<text class="pointIndex" x="-4px" y="-10px">1</text>` (in this case `1`) so I did `deleteCircle.parentNode + ' .pointIndex'`. But I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document':
>   '[object SVGGElement] .pointIndex' is not a valid selector.

Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: because you can not add an element and a string together.

Answer (score 1):

Here `deleteCircle.parentNode` is an html element and cannot concat it with any string and use as selector.

You can simply get the text content as shown below, where `deleteCircle` is the circle element.

```
var circleText = d3.select(deleteCircle.parentNode).select("text").text();
```

Comment: Though I hit the enter 6 seconds before you, I learned this technique from you. Maybe thats the reason our answer looks similiar :D

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add an element and a string together it throws an error.

If you want to access the `parent` of a `circle` and then find the `text` element inside that and grab the `text`, you can do it like this.

```
function deletePoint(deleteCircle) {
    var circleText = d3.select(deleteCircle.node()).select(function(){return this.parentNode;});
    console.log(circleText.select('text').text());   }
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1087qndn/)